# Python-Telegram bot running locally, but not on Heroku

Tags: heroku, python-telegram-bot

I'm looking to deploy my python-telegram bot on Heroku but the bot seems to be unresponsive. The .py works just fine locally, but when I deploy it the app builds perfectly and is on, but produces no response on telegram when prompted. The code is very basic but I think I am missing something with the webhook maybe? I'm new to web stuff as my background is more in data science. Below is my code and procfile.

```
"""import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
import ftx
client = ftx.FtxClient()

telegram_bot_token = "token"

updater = Updater(token=telegram_bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(update, context):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text= "1 ***=" + "$" + str(client.get_market('***/USD')['last']) + "\n" + "24 Change =" + str(round(client.get_market('***/USD')['change24h'],2)*100) + "%" + "\n" + "24 Hour Volume =" + str(client.get_market('***/USD')['volumeUsd24h']) + "USD"
                             + "\n"*2 + "The information presented by the price tracker is not meant to be taken as financial advice.")

#I think over here I need something else 
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("***", start))
updater.start_polling()"""

#Proc
"""worker: python bot.py"""
```

I'm happy to write a if dunder main, but I'm unsure still if I even need a webhook. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Heroku doesn't support long polling, so you should use a webhook. `python-telegram-bot` comes with a built-in webhook. See [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#heroku) and also this [skeleton-repo](https://github.com/Bibo-Joshi/ptb-heroku-skeleton).

Comment: The following code needs to be changed : 

```dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("***", start))
updater.start_polling() to

updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                          port=int(PORT),
                          webhook_url='https://app-name.herokuapp.com/')
    updater.idle()```